# C++ turn vector iterator into index

Tags: c++, vector, indexing, iterator, distance

I've got a question.
I have a vector that contains tuples:

```
vector<tuple<int, int> > my_vector
```

Let's say I want to turn my for loop iterator in an index for whatever reason:

```
// Example program
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

int main()
{        
    vector<tuple<int, int> > my_vector;
    my_vector.push_back(make_tuple(1, 1));
    my_vector.push_back(make_tuple(2, 2));
    my_vector.push_back(make_tuple(3, 3));

    for (auto iterator : my_vector)
    {
        size_t index = distance(my_vector.begin(), iterator);
    }       
}
```

I honestly do not understand what I have to change to get it running. The problems seems to be my use of the iterator in `distance`. Maybe somebody can give me some advice.

Comment: Your `iterator` is a vector element, not in iterator.

Comment: Use a regular for-loop if you need the index.

Comment: `I honestly do not understand what I have to change to get it running.` So, you're implying that this doesn't "run"? How do you know that it doesn't "run"? What does it do instead? Is there no error message?

Comment: The correct wording would be `for (auto element : my_vector)`

Comment: If `C++20` is available you could use a [range-based for loop with an init statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

```
for (range_declaration : range_expression) 
    loop_statement
```

is roughly equivalent to this code:

```
for (auto begin = range_expression.begin(), end = range_expression.end(); 
     begin != end; ++begin)
{
    range_declaration = *begin;
    loop_statement
}
```

Note the `*` operator. So, `range_declaration` is not the iterator, but an element, it points to.

If you need an index, use plain `for` loop:

```
for (std::size_t index = 0; index < my_vector.size(); ++index)
     loop_statement
```

Answer (score 4):

> C++ turn vector iterator into index

You can do it like this:

```
std::size_t index = std::distance(std::begin(my_vector), iterator);
```

But before you can get an index from an iterator, you first need to have an iterator. Example of an iterator to a vector:

```
// iterator to i'th element
auto iterator = std::next(my_vector.begin(), i);
```

---

> ```
> for (auto iterator : my_vector)
> ```

Just naming a variable iterator does not make it an iterator. A range based loop goes over the *elements* of the container. The elements of this vector are tuples, not iterators.

The canonical way to have an index when iterating elements of a vector is to use a traditional index loop:

```
using my_vec_t = decltype(my_vector);
for (my_vec_t::size_type i = 0; i < my_vector.size(); i++)
```

---

If you really want to have the index in a range-for loop, that's possible using pointers:

```
auto* front = &my_vector.front();
for (auto& element : my_vector)
{
    auto index = std::distance(front, &element);
}
```

Comment: Great answer! But how can `std::distance` accept raw pointers, not only iterators? It seems like it accepts only iterators, according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance).

Comment: @starriet Pointers are iterators.

Answer (score 0):

In the range based loop it is value of a container is assigned not an iterator.

So either use the following for loop

```
#include <iterator>

//...

for (auto it = std::begin(my_vector); it != std::end(my_vector); ++it)
{
    size_t index = std::distance(std::begin(my_vector), it);
}
```

Or use an ordinary for loop with an index.

```
for (std::vector<std::tuple<int, int>>::size_type i = 0; i != my_vector.size(); i++)
{
    auto it = std::next(std::begin(myvector), i);
}
```